# AngularJS: Delete button working in main page but not in in-depth view page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I updated the codes with a set of codes, which uses $rootScope.

After that, my **delete button no longer works** in the post view page, but it still works in the main post page. Both delete button uses the same code.

Any suggestions how to test whats causing the errors or display some error codes to identify the problem area?

Attached is a plunkr that somewhat resembles the basic issue. (Delete code is different)
http://plnkr.co/edit/I2qrAznO3cTHjos3FqUm?p=preview

**html**

```
<ion-view ng-controller="PostViewCtrl">
<a ng-click="deletePost(post)">DELETE</a>
```

**js for delete function**

```
app.controller('PostViewCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Post, Auth) {

      $scope.deletePost = function(post) {   //delete function action
        Post.delete(post);
      };
```

**factory for delete function**

```
app.factory('Post', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {

  var Post = {
    all: posts,
    delete: function (post) {    //delete function from factory
      return posts.$remove(post);
    },
```

**This is the new code added which broke the delete function**

```
app.factory('Geolocation', function($q, $window, $rootScope) { 
    return function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
             etc.......
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Just telling use the function is broke doesnt help.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, the delete button no longer works. When I click deleting a post, nothing happens. I wrote it at the top, sorry should have bold it.

Comment: Use can install BATARANG which is a chrome extension for debugging angular.js. It will show you all the scopes in a hierarchial way.

Comment: @ashfaq.p Batarang doesnt seem to work with the new angularJS. I was not able to edit the codes and track check the scopes.

Comment: ng-inspector could help https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj